# Javascript - How to do a async load of a image without using/showing it on a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I want to use a gif image (loding indication - speening wheel), when a user is uploading a image (ajax). But I want to display it immediately after a user hits "upload" button, with no delay caused by downloading the gif image.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new image element, set its source attribute and place it somewhere in the document once it has finished loading:

```
var img = $("<img />").attr('src', 'http://somedomain.com/image.jpg')
    .on("load", function() {
        if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
            alert('broken image!');
        } else {
            $("#something").append(img);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Note that `.load()` event was deprecated in v1.8 (in 2012) and removed in v3.0.  The event still exists as `.on("load", ` so I've updated the answer directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can pre-load images in different ways, see [this link](http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/).

```
        var images = new Array()
        function preload() {
            for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
                images[i] = new Image()
                images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
            }
        }
        preload(
            "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-001.jpg",
            "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-002.jpg",
            "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-003.jpg"
        )
```

Is the javascript way, the website also shows how to do it in html and css, depending on how you would like to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Using css

```
<div id="preload">
  <img src="ajax-indicator.gif"/>
</div>

#preload {
    display: none;
}
```

the browser will load the image even it's not visible.